# Can I change the "new tab" button in Google Chrome 86?

Tags: google-chrome, mouse

Ever since I updated to Google Chrome 86, i've had a hard time clicking the "New Tab" button (see image) [google chrome's "new tab" button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WewfK.png)

In previous versions of Chrome, my mouse could be at the very top of my screen and still be within the bounds to click the button, however, in this version, my mouse must be very specifically inside the circle. My muscle memory is to always move my mouse to the very top of my screen and click it, now I need to be very particular in clicking inside the circle.

Has anyone else noticed this?

Is it possible to change the bounding box of the New Tab button?

Comment: I understand the overall problem very well. Chrome and now Chromium Edge are the very same here. So you need to adapt yourself to how the mouse clicks change and work. I had to do the same thing myself.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. I got the same thing, and it's really annoying. Sadly, we can't help since it's a Chrome specific option. Maybe opening a ticket at Google will advice the devs that they should bring the good old way back.

Comment: I always click directly on the + symbol,  I never noticed before that you could just click near it, so this won't affect me.

Comment: If you look into alternate UI/skinning in your OS you might be able to do this, but that would require to use the built-in OS UI elements that the alternate skin/theme would be able to modify. I don't think Chrome has used built-in UI elements for its host OSes in a while.

Comment: This is a good example of how [Fitts' law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitts%27s_law) allowed users to open new tabs with ease. With the new update, they've essentially reduced the hitbox of the new tab button from infinite height to a specific amount of pixels. This is **not** something users should adapt to, I hope this change is reverted quickly.

Comment: Sounds like Google is continuing to make changes that convolute the UI. I'm still using version 70 from 2018 for this reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lol, someone literally copy-pasted my post onto Google Support forums https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/76042189?hl=en

This issue is now fixed in version `86.0.4240.111`

Your mouse can now be at the very top of the screen and still be within the bounds to click the button